# Sending Spring Integration messages over RMI seamlessly?

Tags: rmi, spring-integration

Is there a way to send Spring Messages over an int-rmi:outbound to int-rmi:inbound gateway?

I've got two components that both use Spring Integration and I'd ideally like to send a Message between them so the receiving component can then seamlessly use a router or filters to decide where that message ends up.

The components are both written in Java, but are running in separate processes (Probably on the same machine but it's not guaranteed).

I've managed to use Spring integration to get **Component 1** to call a Method on **Component 2** and then for **Component 2** to call a Method on **Component 1**, using RMI, and I Set the parameter of the RMI method to a Message which I can then obtain a channel and send into Spring Integration's flow.

But I was wondering if there was a way to skip that last step? And just have the Message flow through the two applications.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it isn't clear what is the issue.

Actually it works out-of-the-box.

[Here is a test-case as a sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-rmi/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/rmi/BackToBackTests-context.xml)

Comment: Yes, the outbound/inbound gateways exchange the entire message.